# 'Questions ' object is not iterable Django

Tags: django

I have a model called Question. Model allow users to create new questions. 
I'm trying to populate multiple forms with a queryset of objects.
The problem appears when I attempt to initial with a queryset. I get this error

```
 'Question' object is not iterable


File "C:\mysite\pet\views.py" in DisplayAll
294.             formset = form(initial=q)
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
question= forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=51)
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ('question',)
```

views

```
def DisplayAll(request):
    q = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    form = formset_factory(QuestionForm)
    formset = form(initial=q)
    return render(request,'question.html',{'formset':formset})
```

template

```
 {% for f in formset %}
 {{f}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: try appending a call to the "all()" function in `form(initial=q)` i.e. make it `form(initial=q.all())`

Comment: Ok, from memory that error basically means its expecting a list of objects in the query but not getting one...

Comment: try with `initial=[question.question for question in q]`, that should be it. You're passing a queryset object, but `initial` expects values to fill the formset with

Comment: didn't expect it to work, just wanted to be sure the problem was going away after that. posting the correct solution now :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Initial` expects a dictionary of values, so you just need to change your queryset like this:

```
q = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) about `values()`